# Empty arraylist when pass to another class

Tags: java, arraylist

I have made an arraylist  in one class but when I pass it to another class it is empty. There are elements in one class but in another class it is empty.

Here is my code in one class.

```
System.out.println(mot);
Paint p=new Paint(mot, start );
```

Here is my code in another class

```
ArrayList<String> motif;
ArrayList<Integer> number;
NewJFrame j=new NewJFrame();

public Paint(ArrayList<String> motif,ArrayList<Integer> number) {
   initComponents();
   motif=new ArrayList();
   number=new ArrayList<>();
   j=new NewJFrame();
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
   System.out.print(j.mot);
}
```

Please tell me how to solve my problem of empty arraylist?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Where do you use `motif` or `number`? What is `j.mot` or just `mot`?

Comment: `motif=new ArrayList();` will make the passed arraylist `motif` to be new instance of arraylist, and thus since its new , its empty.

Comment: I have not use motif or number. Mot is string arraylist in another class (NewJFrame). When I call it in another class i-e with j.mot it gives me empty arraylist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change these lines of code:

```
motif=new ArrayList();
number=new ArrayList<>();
```

to

```
this.motif = motif;
this.number = number;
```

Answer (score 1):

This two lines make new instance of listes, try to change them:

```
motif=new ArrayList();
number=new ArrayList<>();
```

This would be better:

```
this.motif = motif;
this.number = number;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [addAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29):

```
 public Paint(ArrayList<String> pMotif,ArrayList<Integer> pNumber) {
    initComponents();
    motif=new ArrayList();
    motif.addAll(pMotif); //use addAll 
    number=new ArrayList<>();
    motif.addAll(pNumber); //use addAll
```

Answer (score 1):

You're overwriting the copies of `motif` and `number` you got with new (empty) versions in these lines

```
motif=new ArrayList();
number=new ArrayList<>();
```

If you want to set your class members to an empty ArrayList, refer to them with `this`:

```
this.motif = new ArrayList();
this.number = new ArrayList<>();
```

If you want to set them to the ArrayLists passed in, do this:

```
this.motif = motif;
this.number = number;
```

Another option would be copying the values from the ArrayLists passed in:

```
this.motif = new ArrayList(motif);
this.number = new ArrayList<>(number);
```

Answer (score 1):

you are passing the value to another class, so you should tell your compiler to use current object i.e this object.....

you are assigning the values using Constructor So, alwayz use either "this" or "super" ( which is first statement in Constructor )

use

this.motif = motif; 
this.number = number;